# My tab fragments showing user's posts do not work correctly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app crashes when scrolling down feed fragments. Like I said, one of them is meant to show every user's post and the other is to show only followed. On crash logcat says:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.ca_ltd.ting.Home.CameraFragment cannot be cast to
>   com.example.ca_ltd.ting.Home.HomeFragment at
>   com.example.ca_ltd.ting.Home.HomeActivity.onLoadMoreItems(HomeActivity.java:43)
>   at
>   com.example.ca_ltd.ting.Utils.MainfeedListAdapter.loadMoreData(MainfeedListAdapter.java:273)
>   at
>   com.example.ca_ltd.ting.Utils.MainfeedListAdapter.getView(MainfeedListAdapter.java:254)

Do not get misleaded about CameraFragment name. First it was meant to be really a fragment that allows users to take photos but later I have replaced that code with HomeFragment code and made two changes to make all posts appear in fragment, not like in HomeFragment where only followed users posts do so. Please help:).

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPhotos;
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPaginatedPhotos;
    private ArrayList<String> mFollowing;
    private ListView mListView;
    private MainfeedListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mResults;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mFollowing = new ArrayList<>();
        mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

        getFollowing();

        return view;
    }

    private void getFollowing(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getFollowing: searching for following");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_following))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                            singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue());

                    mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());
                }
                mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                //get the photos
                getPhotos();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getPhotos(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getPhotos: getting photos");
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        for(int i = 0; i < mFollowing.size(); i++){
            final int count = i;
            Query query = reference
                    .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                    .child(mFollowing.get(i))
                    .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                    .equalTo(mFollowing.get(i));
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Photo photo = new Photo();
                        Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                        photo.setCaption(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_caption)).toString());
                        photo.setTags(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_tags)).toString());
                        photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_photo_id)).toString());
                        photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).toString());
                        photo.setDate_created(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_date_created)).toString());
                        photo.setImage_path(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_image_path)).toString());

                        ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
                        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                .child(getString(R.string.field_comments)).getChildren()){
                            Comment comment = new Comment();
                            comment.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getUser_id());
                            comment.setComment(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getComment());
                            comment.setDate_created(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getDate_created());
                            comments.add(comment);
                        }

                        photo.setComments(comments);
                        mPhotos.add(photo);
                    }
                    if(count >= mFollowing.size() -1){
                        //display our photos
                        displayPhotos();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void displayPhotos(){
        mPaginatedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
        if(mPhotos != null){
            try{
                Collections.sort(mPhotos, new Comparator<Photo>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Photo o1, Photo o2) {
                        return o2.getDate_created().compareTo(o1.getDate_created());
                    }
                });

                int iterations = mPhotos.size();

                if(iterations > 10){
                    iterations = 10;
                }

                mResults = 10;
                for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
                    mPaginatedPhotos.add(mPhotos.get(i));
                }

                mAdapter = new MainfeedListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_mainfeed_listitem, mPaginatedPhotos);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayMorePhotos(){
        Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: displaying more photos");

        try{

            if(mPhotos.size() > mResults && mPhotos.size() > 0){

                int iterations;
                if(mPhotos.size() > (mResults + 10)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: there are greater than 10 more photos");
                    iterations = 10;
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: there is less than 10 more photos");
                    iterations = mPhotos.size() - mResults;
                }

                //add the new photos to the paginated results
                for(int i = mResults; i < mResults + iterations; i++){
                    mPaginatedPhotos.add(mPhotos.get(i));
                }
                mResults = mResults + iterations;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}
```

Camera Fragment

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraFragment";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPhotos;
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPaginatedPhotos;
    private ArrayList<String> mFollowing;
    private ListView mListView;
    private MainfeedListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mResults;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mFollowing = new ArrayList<>();
        mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

        getFollowing();

        return view;
    }

   private void getFollowing(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getFollowing: searching for following");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
       Query query = reference
               .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                            singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue());

                    mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());
                }
                mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                //get the photos
                getPhotos();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getPhotos(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getPhotos: getting photos");
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        for(int i = 0; i < mFollowing.size(); i++){
            final int count = i;
            Query query = reference
                    .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                    .child(mFollowing.get(i))
                    .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                    .equalTo(mFollowing.get(i));
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Photo photo = new Photo();
                        Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                        photo.setCaption(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_caption)).toString());
                        photo.setTags(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_tags)).toString());
                        photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_photo_id)).toString());
                        photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).toString());
                        photo.setDate_created(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_date_created)).toString());
                        photo.setImage_path(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_image_path)).toString());

                        ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                .child(getString(R.string.field_comments)).getChildren()){
                            Comment comment = new Comment();
                            comment.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getUser_id());
                            comment.setComment(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getComment());
                            comment.setDate_created(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getDate_created());
                            comments.add(comment);
                        }

                        photo.setComments(comments);
                        mPhotos.add(photo);
                    }
                    if(count >= mFollowing.size() -1){
                        //display our photos
                        displayPhotos();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void displayPhotos(){
        mPaginatedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
        if(mPhotos != null){
            try{
                Collections.sort(mPhotos, new Comparator<Photo>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Photo o1, Photo o2) {
                        return o2.getDate_created().compareTo(o1.getDate_created());
                    }
                });

                int iterations = mPhotos.size();

                if(iterations > 10){
                    iterations = 10;
                }

                mResults = 10;
                for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
                    mPaginatedPhotos.add(mPhotos.get(i));
                }

                mAdapter = new MainfeedListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_mainfeed_listitem, mPaginatedPhotos);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayMorePhotos(){
        Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: displaying more photos");

        try{

            if(mPhotos.size() > mResults && mPhotos.size() > 0){

                int iterations;
                if(mPhotos.size() > (mResults + 10)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: there are greater than 10 more photos");
                    iterations = 10;
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "displayMorePhotos: there is less than 10 more photos");
                    iterations = mPhotos.size() - mResults;
                }

                //add the new photos to the paginated results
                for(int i = mResults; i < mResults + iterations; i++){
                    mPaginatedPhotos.add(mPhotos.get(i));
                }
                mResults = mResults + iterations;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "displayPhotos: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}
```

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        MainfeedListAdapter.OnLoadMoreItemsListener{

    @Override
    public void onLoadMoreItems() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMoreItems: displaying more photos");
        HomeFragment fragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
        //CameraFragment fragment2 = (CameraFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager_container + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
       CameraFragment fragment2 = (CameraFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager_container + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

       if(fragment != null){
            fragment.displayMorePhotos();}

           if(fragment2 != null){
            fragment2.displayMorePhotos();}


    }

    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;
    private static final int HOME_FRAGMENT = 1;

    private Context mContext = HomeActivity.this;

    //firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    //widgets
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayoutParent);

        setupFirebaseAuth();

        initImageLoader();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupViewPager();

    }



    public void onCommentThreadSelected(Photo photo, String callingActivity){
        Log.d(TAG, "onCommentThreadSelected: selected a coemment thread");

        ViewCommentsFragment fragment  = new ViewCommentsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(getString(R.string.photo), photo);
        args.putString(getString(R.string.home_activity), getString(R.string.home_activity));
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.view_comments_fragment));
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void hideLayout(){
        Log.d(TAG, "hideLayout: hiding layout");
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public void showLayout(){
        Log.d(TAG, "hideLayout: showing layout");
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(mFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            showLayout();
        }
    }


    private void initImageLoader(){
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(mContext);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for adding the 3 tabs: Camera, Home, Messages
     */
    private void setupViewPager(){
        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment());//index 1
        adapter.addFragment(new CameraFragment());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

      //  tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_instagram_black);
         tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow);

    }





    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, this,bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }


     /*
    ------------------------------------ Firebase ---------------------------------------------
     */

    /**
     * checks to see if the @param 'user' is logged in
     * @param user
     */
    private void checkCurrentUser(FirebaseUser user){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCurrentUser: checking if user is logged in.");

        if(user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Setup the firebase auth object
     */
    private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                //check if the user is logged in
                checkCurrentUser(user);

                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(HOME_FRAGMENT);
        checkCurrentUser(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


}
```

And here is MainfeedListAdapter because it would be above 30000 letters.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1qYcLtn_DV8andxWUdiQ28tWWM

Comment: Check your logic in `onLoadMoreItems()`'. You're retrieving the current `ViewPager` `Fragment`, then trying to cast it to both `HomeFragment` and `CameraFragment`.

Comment: Can you explain me more accurately what to do?

Comment: Hey, are you online?

Comment: Well, you know which `Fragment` is on which page, so check `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()` before you try to cast the return from `findFragmentByTag()`.